# ExceptionFilterAttribute not triggered when using Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API, in one of my controller actions I use a Task.Factory.StartNew call.

However, this does not trigger the Exception filter I configured when an exception is thrown inside the task.

**Controller.cs**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() => DoTheThing())
            .ContinueWith(tsk => { throw new Exception("Webhook Exception", tsk.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

**ExceptionFilter.cs**

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), new
            {
                Message = "Critical Error",
                ExceptionMessage = "An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator.",
                Type = ExceptionType.Unhandled
            }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            ReasonPhrase = "Critical Error"
        });
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MyApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

I can debug and the ContinueWith method is triggered and the new Exception is thrown. But the filter is not triggered.

Comment: You're not *observing* the (re)thrown `Exception`, hence it's an `Unobserved Exceptions`. See: [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I understand the problem now. I'm trying to do the impossible as the filter will only catch exceptions in my action. But I want my action to return immediately before my task ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is not triggered because the exception is thrown in the thread different from controller action method thread. You could:

1. Await task

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
   {
       await Task.Factory
           .StartNew(() => DoTheThing())
           .ContinueWith(tsk => { throw new Exception("Webhook Exception", tsk.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

       return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
   ```
2. Wait Task

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post()
   {
       var task = Task.Factory
                      .StartNew(() => DoTheThing())
                      .ContinueWith(tsk => { throw new Exception("Webhook Exception", tsk.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

       task.Wait();

       return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
   ```

All of these approaches rethrow the exception in action method and the filter catches it.

Comment: Marking as correct as it answers my question. It's not the solution I wanted as I intended to return from my action immediately and not wait for the task to complete. But I understand now that this is in conflict with the design of the filter which only catches exceptions within a controller action thread.

Comment: Actually the exception filter catches all exceptions, but Task “handles” them in own thread. Anyway you return the 'HttpStatusCode.OK' immediately from action method, but then you return another Status  - 'InternalServerError' from the filter. However, the request has been already processed and client has got response. You could log exception in continuation task after return from action, but not rewrite response status.